# how to properly use char[int]

Tags: c++

I'm trying to copy an std::string into char*, so I've proceeded this way:

```
    char porta[10];
std::string p = "7855";
p[p.length()] = '\0';
std::copy(p.begin(), p.end(), porta);
```

When I do this, I get "7855ìos", I've tried to replate `porta`'s datatype by `char*`, but this still the same.

How do I to get "7855" in `porta`, please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: p[p.length()] = '\0'; is this typo ?, do you mean porta[p.length()] = '\0'; ?

Comment: it is not copying the null char you can use c_str or set porta[p.length()]='\0';

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  When interfacing with legacy C, I generally use `std::vector<char>`; since C++11, you can use `std::string` directly (since it is now guaranteed to be contiguous).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `std::string::c_str()`?

Comment: You still need to copy it into the buffer. `std::string::c_str()` only returns a pointer to an internal buffer which can go out of scope with the string.

Comment: where do I need to write that?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @sandrstar - on the contrary, although concise, this is an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As Kiske1 said, if you want a C string, you can use `c_str()` to get a NULL-terminated string. That will also work if you want copy of that string in the char array:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    // Be careful about overflow!
    char porta[10];
    std::string p = "7855";
    std::copy(p.c_str(), p.c_str() + p.length() + 1,  porta);
    std::cout << porta << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why doesn't `std::copy(p.begin(), p.end(), porta)` work?

Comment: As it is not guarantied that `std::string` will include NULL terminator (prior to C++11).

Comment: Yes, he is, but I'm not sure that's the best practice :).